# Redis versus hardware cache

Tags: caching, redis

Do tools like Redis provide control over the hardware cache present in the computer or does it run on the computer RAM? If it is the latter, how can it give better performance than the existing hardware cache which is controlled by the operating system?

Comment: Hardware cache? Cache is always stored in some kind of memory, either disk or RAM....

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of scattered reading I think I have got a better idea about this. So answering the question in case someone else has this question too.

1. The cache in a computer is not controlled by the Operating System. It is a part of the micro architecture. No software access can 'alter' cache configuration. On a linux machine, typing `vi /proc/cpuinfo` will show the cache size and alignment as prescribed by the chip manufacturer.
2. Tools like Redis and memcached,'cache' data by persisting it in the physical memory (RAM) of a machine. It is still caused caching as this prevents the data from being written to disk and hence gives faster access.